# C++ - most popular framework for interacting with SQL?

Tags: c++, sql

I am a computer science student and I want to do a personal project demonstrating some skills that I have learned. Recently I learned how to use `SQL` with `PHP`. Since `PHP` isn't as relevant as it once was, I was hoping someone could point me towards a more commonly used back-end tool where I still interact with my database through `SQL` queries. In my question, I specifically asked about a `C++` framework since I am most comfortable with `C++`, but if there are much more common frameworks for what I'm looking for that use `Java` or `Python`, that would work as well.

Doing a quick google search gave me a very very large list of potential frameworks, so I was hoping someone with more knowledge in the field can point me towards one that employers would find the most relevant.

On a side note, I was also wondering if a framework is completely necessary, or if I can create my back-end just using native `c++`? If so, is this a valuable skill to look into?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Off topic for Stack Overflow. Recommend taking this question down and asking over at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. You might need a bit of tweaking to meet their rules, so give http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help a read first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out QT for the C++ GUI & MySQL for the backend...

Comment: I'm sure the question was "SQL" not "MySQL" they're different.

Comment: thanks, i totally slipped on that. im a MySQL user myself, guess its just resides in the subconscious.... kudos my man

Comment: either way you can use either or and why not just go open source no?

Comment: A MySQL connector won't connect / work with a SQL database. The syntax is different too. [Here is a list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs) of C++ libraries, where you can find some Database libraries.

Comment: i know.... im saying you can use SQL or MySQL with C++